# mongodb query filtering by ranging compound field calculated

Tags: mongodb

Say collection has structure like

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5fd8825285e55e381e278b30"), 
  "name": "some name",
  "ts" : {
    "seconds" : NumberLong(1608024657), "nanos" : 519000000
  }
}
```

How to filter for some `((ts.seconds * 1000,000,000) + ts.nanos) < 1234567890123456` ?

Query filter should be from some fields calculated to a value, and filter with that value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$sum` and `$multiply` operators to do the arithmetic:

```js
db.yourCollection.find({
    $expr: { $lt: [ {
        $sum: [ { $multiply: ["$ts.seconds", 1000000000] }, "$ts.nanos"]
    }, 1234567890123456] }
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work, Error:
`MongoDB server version: 4.4.2
uncaught exception: ReferenceError: ts is not defined :
...`

Comment: @Michaelzh Apologies...the field names need to be in double quotes.  Please try it again.

Comment: Doesn't work: Error:
`MongoDB server version: 4.4.2
Error: error: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Failed to optimize expression :: caused by :: $multiply only supports numeric types, not string",
 "code" : 16555,
....}`

Comment: Use `"$ts.seconds"`, `"$ts.nanos"`, etc.